# 組み合わせでの関連するデータを管理する方法

Tags: sql, database

列が30個くらいあるテーブルがあると仮定して、レコードは膨大に日々増えるとします。
列は30個を当初固定しますが、35個等に増やす可能性があります。

AAA,BBB,FFF

AAA,CCC,DDD

BBB,CCC,EEE

というようなデータが入っている場合、

AAAが組み合わせにある他の関連するデータを探すために、入力フォームに入力すると、
BBB,CCC,DDD,FFF
が関連するデータとして表示され、

CCCが組み合わせにある他の関連するデータを探すために、入力フォームに入力すると、
AAA,BBB,DDD,EEEが
関連するデータとして表示される

という仕組みを作る場合は、
データの保存、検索の考え方、
RDBでのテーブルの設計の考え方は、
どのようにするのが定石でしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 原文の例示でパターンが理解できなかったのですが、CCCの場合は AAA, BBB, DDD, **EEE** の誤りでしょうか？

Comment: はい、ご指摘ありがとうございます。FFFではなくEEEでした。本文も修正させていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

質問の意図を取り違えているかもしれませんが、
連想元(例えば'AAA')と連想先(例えば'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'FFF')の関係を関連テーブルで表すのはどうでしょうか。
以下、関連の方向は単方向(AAAの関連データにBBBが存在する場合でも、必ずしもBBBの関連データにAAAが存在するとは限らない)として記載しています。
(双方向の場合は、associationの登録時に少し考慮が必要になります(`key_content_id`の値と`value_content_id`の値が逆になっているだけのレコード登録を拒否する必要がある)。)

[image: ER図]

content:

```
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
|  1 | AAA  |
|  2 | BBB  |
|  3 | CCC  |
|  4 | DDD  |
|  5 | EEE  |
|  6 | FFF  |
+----+------+
```

association(の一部):

```
+----+----------------+------------------+
| id | key_content_id | value_content_id |
+----+----------------+------------------+
|  1 |              1 |                2 |
|  2 |              1 |                3 |
|  3 |              1 |                4 |
|  4 |              1 |                6 |
|  5 |              3 |                1 |
|  6 |              3 |                2 |
|  7 |              3 |                4 |
|  8 |              3 |                5 |
+----+----------------+------------------+
```

---

contentに新しく以下のレコードを登録する場合、

```
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
|  7 | GGG  |
+----+------+
```

例えば'AAA'の連想先に'GGG'があり、'GGG'の連想先に'BBB','CCC'があるのであれば、associationテーブルに新しく登録すべきデータは以下のようになります。

```
+----+----------------+------------------+
| id | key_content_id | value_content_id |
+----+----------------+------------------+
|  9 |              1 |                7 |
| 10 |              7 |                3 |
| 11 |              7 |                3 |
+----+----------------+------------------+
```

関連をたどれば連想元から連想先を引いてくることができます。
SQL:

```
select v.data from content v where id in (
    select value_content_id from association 
    inner join (
        select id from content where data = 'AAA'
    ) k
    on association.key_content_id = k.id
);
```

`k`(keyの意), `v`(valueの意)は、`FROM`句に登場させているcontentテーブルの[別名](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx)です。文中、異なる意味で2回(連想元として、連想先として)出てきていますので、区別がつくように別の名前をつけています。

実際にやりたいことを図で表してみると以下のようになると思います。

[image: 処理概念]

これを文章で表すと次の手順で所望のデータを取得する、ということになります。

1. associationに登録された関連を取得するためにcontentから'AAA'のIDを取得する
2. 取得したIDを用い、'AAA'の連想先IDをassociationから実際に取得する
3. 取得した連想先IDを用いcontentから連想先の実体を取得する

以下、それぞれについて見ていきます。

#### associationに登録された関連を取得するためにcontentから'AAA'のIDを取得する

前述のSQLのうち、以下の部分が該当します。

```
select id from content where data = 'AAA'
```

実際にはこれに別名`k`をつけていますので、次のようなテーブルができたと考えてください。

[image: kテーブル]

`id`というカラムを持ち、レコード数が1のテーブルです。

#### 取得したIDを用い、'AAA'の連想先IDをassociationから取得する

前述のSQLのうち、次の部分が該当します。

```
select value_content_id from association 
inner join k
on association.key_content_id = k.id
```

`association` と `k` を inner join したテーブルは以下のようなものになります。

[image: assosiationとkのjoin table]

'AAA'のID`1`を`key_content_id`に持つレコードのみが存在します。
すなわち、このテーブルの`value_content_id`が'AAA'の連想先IDということになります。

#### 取得した連想先IDを用いcontentから連想先の実体を取得する

```
select v.data from content v where id in (2,3,4,6)
```

`content`から指定した`id`の`data`を取得します。これが連想先です。

Comment: yukihaneさん、一案ありがとうございます。
SQL構文の知識が初心者（ファイルメーカーなどである程度のリレーションモデルは理解できます）ということで教えていただければと思います。


＊）SQL中のvとkって何か教えていただけると助かります。（ググって調べるつもりではあります）

＊）関連の方向が単方向か、双方向というのはどういうことでしょうか？


＊）contentテーブルは、利用するデータを用意しておく、制限するという意味では、ある意味マスターテーブルみたいなものですよね？
associationテーブルは、私の原文のテーブルのレコードが増えていくときに、associationテーブルに記録するという処理をするということで良いでしょうか？
原文には連想元AAA,CCCの場合で記載しましたが、原文テーブルができた時点で、連想元が全て（AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF）の場合での関連が、associationテーブルに記載されるという感じになるかと思います。
ということで「双方向」ということになるのかな。。。。


PS:テーブルの記号を使った表ってどうやって書いてるのでしょう？Markdown？

Comment: あらら、コメントは改行とかできないのかな。。。

Comment: @SmokeyBlues 質問欄の方に追記した方がよろしいかと。

Comment: 質問に対する回答(補足)を本文に追記しました。/テーブルは http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/ からリンクされていたテキスト整形サービス http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html を利用して作成しています。

Comment: @argus 回答１の返信的なレスは、自分の質問を編集して追記の方が良いのですか。。。ありがとうございます、了解です。^^

Comment: @yukihane テキスト整形について助かります、次回の投稿で使ってみます。一旦教えていただいたsqlの理解に立ち止まっています。理解進みましたら再度ご質問させていただきます。

Comment: すみません、sqlですが、入れ子と別名とjoinに慣れず、何度分解しても読めません。申し訳ないですが、和訳していただけないでしょうか？

Comment: レス遅くなってごめんなさい。めちゃくちゃ丁寧にご説明いただき、完璧に理解できました。感謝感激です！
まだテストできてないので、実際にテストしてみます。ちょっと新たな疑問点があるのでまたご連絡させていただきます。